# error MSB3202: The project file [project file] was not found when compiling in visual studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, compilation

I compile and get

```
1>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1336,5): 
error MSB3202: 
The project file "..\..\AFolder\AnotherFolder\MyProject.vbproj" was not found.
```

I compile again and all works(!)

Anyone else have got this problem and a remedy?
*I know the question is too vague for SO but there is quite a chance someone has got a problem similar to this.*

The folder and project file exist - the successful compile proves that.
In the same solution other projects succeed at first compile.
Note that this is in VS (2012) and *not a build machine*.
Windows 8.1.
The project is several years old and is a mix of c# and vbnet.

Update:
I do some compiles and VS seems to find the earlier not found projects. Now it instead doesn't find new ones. Until it finally decides on not finding `app.config`.
This one is strange too: VS looks in the solution root and not in the project folder. I tried putting a copy of `app.config` in the solution root to see what happened but the same error 'couldnt find appconfig'.

Comment: You cannot get a reliable answer for any kind of "the file wasn't there before, now its back" behavior.  This is an environmental problem, we just don't know nearly enough about your machine to have a guess at it.  All you can do is gather evidence with a tool like SysInternals' Process Monitor.  Update your question with what you found out.

Comment: I would assume that maybe some of the following apply:

1. You have a wrong project Build order.
So it doesn't compile at first time because its missing some projects or Dll's and at second attempt
it can find them because they were build afterwards.

2. Check your userrights or start VS as administrator and see if it behaves different.

Let me know what happened and we can try to find it from there on

Comment: I sometimes run as an administrator (web project, needed for debugging). Checking the build order has been on my agenda but I can sometimes clean&build at first shot. Besides - unless I have some sort of dynamic stuff, doesn't VS figure out build order well enough?

Comment: You wrote that the files are several years old so i guess it might be a problem with some auto generated files. Have you already deleted the .suo and the .user file in your projects directory ? Maybe Visual Studio produced some corrupt files while updating to VS2012.

Comment: I continue to have the problem to and fro.  Right now the build shows ------ Build started: Project: MDIFramework, Configuration: Debug x86 ------  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets(78,9): error MSB3041: Unable to create a manifest resource name for "MyMenuItem.resx". Could not find file 'C:\AFolder\AProject\MyMenuItem.vb'.  which is weird since the MyMenuItem.vb file does not exist in the MDIFramework to begin with. Why does VS search for a file that is not referenced from said project?

Comment: For future reference: When building project A I got an 'error MSB3104: The referenced assembly "C:\AFolder\AProject\AnExternal.dll" was not found.' which is totally correct since it resides in 'C:\AFolder\ExternalLibs\'. ProjectA does not even reference AnExternal.dll and nothing ProjectA references references said AnExternal.dll. But ProjectB does and ProjectB has a deeper path and looking into ProjectB's project file I can see that its hint is something like '..\..\..\ExternalLibs' which - run from ProjectA might end up in 'C:\AFolder\AProject'. Why VS mixes the proj files is strange.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if this answer seems too simplistic or patronising but it's from my experience and may help.

We have seen this issue on our build sever and it was down to an "old file cleanup" script that was intermittently being run by sysops.

I have also seen this sort of issue on a build server with an overly zealous anti virus

Comment: Anti virus is a culprit, yes, but I don't think so and can probably not turn it off. I and one another are the only ones running Win8.1. (and only I have problems of my magnitude) The rest are running Win7. I believe we are all running the same anti virus but not necessarily.

Comment: Experience is exactly what I am looking for. I am just throwing out a line and hoping that someone has stumbled upon my problem before.

Comment: I would just make sure you exclude your build folder from anti virus scans etc